# Cannot create plpgsql function using psql -f filename option

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am using Postgres 8.4 and I have tried to run  a `create function ...`  script from the command line using

```
psql dbname -U username -f filename
```

or

```
psql -f filename -d dbname -U username
```

and it always results in the following error

> psql:mergenodedata.sql:40: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create"
>   LINE 1: create or replace FUNCTION updNode (oldnodename varchar, ne...

where line 40 is the end of the file

```
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I cut -and-paste file contents of the file into pgadmin or an open psql session, then the `create function` would perfectly.

The code is

```
create or replace FUNCTION updNode (oldnodename varchar, newnodename varchar, scnname varchar, cid integer) returns void AS $$
declare
        oldnodeid integer;
        newnodeid integer;
        scnid integer;
        newcount integer;
        oldcount integer;

BEGIN

raise notice 'doing %', oldnodename;

select id from nodes where nodename = oldnodename and cityid = cid into oldnodeid;
select id from nodes where nodename = newnodename and cityid = cid into newnodeid;
select id from scenario where name = scnname and cityid = cid into scnid;

raise notice 'oldnodeid is %', oldnodeid;
raise notice 'newnodeid is %', newnodeid;
raise notice 'scnid is %', scnid;

select count(*) from collection_node_result where node1id = newnodeid and scenario_collection_id in (
        select id from scenario_collection where scenarioid = scnid into newcount
);

raise notice 'newcount is %', newcount;

select count(*) from collection_node_result where node1id = oldnodeid and scenario_collection_id in (
        select id from scenario_collection where scenarioid = scnid into oldcount
);

raise notice 'oldcount is %', oldcount;


update collection_node_result set node1id = newnodeid where node1id = oldnodeid and scenario_collection_id in (
        select id from scenario_collection where scenarioid = scnid
);


END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Other pages I have refernced are

[Run plpgsql program to update the data in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559038/run-plpgsql-program-to-update-the-data-in-table)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-development-tips.html

Comment: Unrelated fun fact: as, honestly, my only desire right now is to make that "legendary badge" days counter toggle ... I forget: that counter toggles as soon as you have +200 from *anything* on a given day. And that one question that got deleted ... still shows up with +40 ... -40 . So those 4 upvotes still contributed to day 149.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like broken file - some problems can be enforced by BOM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark or ending symbol "^z". Look on file in some hexeditor and check start and check end of file. I had a similar problems, when I used a files created on other operation system.

Comment: Thanks `vi myfile.sql` and then `:set fileencoding=ascii`