# Postgres COPY command running manually but not through JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql

I am running this command via JAVA program builder

```
plpgsql = "\"path_to_psql_executable\psql.exe" -U myuser -w -h myhost -d mydb -a -f "some_path\copy_7133.sql" 2> "log_path\plsql_7133.log\"";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", plpgsql);
Process p = pb.start();
p.getOutputStream().close();
p.waitFor();
```

This is returning me the following error:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xbd CONTEXT:  COPY
>   copy_7133, line 4892

**The catch is if I the run the SQL command manually in cmd, then it is copying all of the data successfully giving me the number of rows inserted. Not able to figure out the reason**

NOTE: The code is causing problem only for one particular file, for rest working fine.

**EDIT**:
Copy command being run:

```
\copy s_m_asset_7140 FROM 'C:\ER\ETL\Unzip_7140\asset.csv' csv HEADER QUOTE '"' ENCODING 'UTF8';
```

The last error the command gave:

> psql:C:/ER/ETL/Unzip_7140/copy_s_m_asset_7140.sql:1: ERROR:  invalid
>   byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0 CONTEXT:  COPY s_m_asset_7140,
>   line 10282

But there doesn't seem to be any special character except a '-'. Not sure what it is not able read.

Few more details abt DB:
show client_encoding;
"UNICODE"

show server_encoding;
"UTF8"

Comment: maybe similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888181/cannot-create-plpgsql-function-using-psql-f-filename-option

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952893/postgresql-encoding-problems-on-windows-when-using-psql-command-line-utility

Comment: Why are you using a `ProcessBuilder` to run the copy command? `copy` is a SQL statement that can also be run directly through JDBC.

Comment: The error message suggests that `psql`  is expecting an UTF-8 encoded file, but your input file isn't. Either change the `client_encoding` in your SQL script to match your input file or change the encoding of the input file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: My file is UTF-8 encoded .csv file. My concern is if there is any encoding issue, then why is the same command running successfully manually?

Comment: Show us the `COPY` statement from `copy_7133.sql` and the offending line in `copy_7133`. The problem is probably that you use a different client encoding in the two cases.

Comment: \copy s_m_asset_7140 FROM 'C:\ER\ETL\Unzip_7140\asset.csv' csv HEADER QUOTE '"' ENCODING 'UTF8';

Comment: Some additional info:show client_encoding;
"UNICODE"

show server_encoding;
"UTF8"

Answer (score 0):

Worked. But still not understand why UTF8 did not work.
I changed the encoding to LATIN1 and it worked

```
\copy s_m_asset_7140 FROM 'C:\ER\ETL\Unzip_7140\asset.csv' csv HEADER QUOTE '"' ENCODING 'LATIN1';
```

Can somebody pls explain why UTF8 did not work?